# What is the best way to modify params nested hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

What is the best way to modify some values in the params hash? For example, this is params hash.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asdasdasd/Wi71c4U3aXasdasdasdpbyMZLYo1sAAmssscQEkv0WsWBDyslcWJxUZ2pPKOQFmJoVZw==", "user_api"=>{"user"=>"asdak", "name"=>"asdada", "friends_attributes"=>{"1566720653776"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "player_name"=>"asda", "player_type"=>"backside", "user_interest"=>"cricket,football,basketball"}, "1566720658089"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "player_name"=>"asdad", "player_type"=>"forward", "user_interest"=>"table_tennis,chess"}}}, "commit"=>"Save User Data"}
```

So from the above params, I need to modify **user_options** value to an array.

```
params.each do |key, user_api_hash|
    if key == "user_api"
      user_api_hash.each do |key, friend_hash|
        if key == "friends_attributes"
          friend_hash.each do |key, value|
            value["user_interest"] = value["user_interest"].split(',')
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I find this approach a bit un-efficient because I would have to iterate exponential times, depending on the number of hash. Can anyone suggest me a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify them rather than returning a new object:

```
(params.dig(:user_api, :friends_attributes) || []).each do |_, attributes|
  attributes['user_interest'] = attributes['user_interest'].split(',')
end
```

- `dig` can access to the keys inside hash and inside other hashes inside them.
- If some key doesn't exist, then it's going to return nil, in that case use an empty array, which will iterate 0 times.
- Inside the user attributes, you can modify them with a simple assignation.